# Changing text color on the edge of animated waves

Tags: html, css, fonts, clipping

I'm trying to apply a clipping mask to animated waves. The end result should look like this:
[image: exsample]

After doing research, I found a [codepen](http://codepen.io/hxd/pen/aLpbh) that works with opacity, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for this contrast.

This is a part of the codepen:

```
<div class="loading wave">
  This is text
</div>

<style>
    .loading{
      font-size:100pt;
      height:120px;
      line-height:110px;
      vertical-align:bottom;
      display:block;
    }

   .wave {
      background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uFpLbYt.png");
      background-clip: text;
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
      animation: wave-animation 1s infinite linear, loading-animation 10s infinite linear alternate;
      background-size: 200px 100px;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      opacity: 1;
   }
</style>
```

I want to use the animation of the codepen on the blue / white color contrast. Does anyone know a sollution?

Comment: Best solution is probably to use an animated gif.

Comment: I've thought about that, but unfortunately the text needs to be changeable depending on other page elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution based on `mix-blend-mode: difference;` for details visit [CSS mix-blend-mode](http://thenewcode.com/1029/Automatic-Text-Contrast-with-CSS-Blend-Modes) and [CSS mix-blend-mode](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/). It is based on this [webpage](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/) and the codepen you had provided.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/uFpLbYt.png');
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
text-shadow:0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
  animation:wave-animation 1s infinite linear, loading-animation 10s infinite linear alternate;
  background-size:450px 300px;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Nocturno Display Medium 4", Georgia;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  height: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  p {
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
word-spacing: 5px;
margin: 0;
  }
}


@import "compass/css3";
body{
 background:#141414; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

@keyframes wave-animation{
  0%{background-position:0 bottom};
  100%{background-position:400px bottom};
}
@keyframes loading-animation{
  0%{background-size:200px 0px};
  100%{background-size:200px 400px};
}
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
<p class="wave">Loading</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Stanislav! It isn't cross browser, but it'll do the trick. IE and Edge are always a pain when making awesome stuff. Anyway, +1!